# npm install giving Error after so many WARN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

My ReactJS project was working all fine till last week but from Sunday its giving below error on npm install:

```
PS C:\Projects\Interface\ClientApp> npm install
npm WARN deprecated material-ui-icons@1.0.0-beta.36: Use @material-ui/icons instead
npm WARN deprecated material-ui@0.20.2: You can now upgrade to @material-ui/core
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not
         recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your
         dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core,
         this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated material-ui-pickers@2.2.4: You can now upgrade to
         @material-ui/pickers. Documentation for v2 can be found at
         https://material-ui-pickers-v2.dmtr-kovalenko.now.sh/
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use
         https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.1.2: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could
         be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not
         recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your
         dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading 
         Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated sw-precache@5.2.1: Please migrate to Workbox:
         https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+.
         Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated sw-toolbox@3.6.0: Please migrate to Workbox:
         https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could
         be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to
         switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain
         bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.81.0: request has been deprecated,
         see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade
         to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
         https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated os-homedir@2.0.0: This is not needed anymore.
         Use `require('os').homedir()` instead.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading
         Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only,
         flatted is its successor. npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version
         has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support).
         Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes,
         and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid 
         support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version has been deprecated in accordance
         with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the 
         latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. 
         If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for 
         older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance
         with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the 
         latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. 
         If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for 
         older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated sntp@1.0.9: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure 
         to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain 
         bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...on" : "10.16.3"
npm ERR!     }'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-06T10_18_35_852Z-debug.log
```

**Note**

1. I have upgraded the npm from 6.9.0 to 6.14.5 then also facing same issue
2. I have removed package.json.lock and node_modules then also facing same issue

Please do let me know what else I am missing ?
--------------My package.json--------------

```
{
  "name": "clientapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.45",
    "@material/typography": "^3.1.0",
    "@trendmicro/react-sidenav": "^0.4.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "flux": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "match-sorter": "^4.0.2",
    "material-grid": "^0.1.0",
    "material-table": "^1.54.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-colors": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "mdbreact": "^4.22.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.5.4",
    "plotly.js": "^1.49.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-bootstrap-tabs": "^1.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-flippy": "^0.1.5",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.5",
    "react-minimal-pie-chart": "^6.0.1",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "^4.5.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-slideshow-image": "^1.4.0",
    "react-sortable-tree": "^2.7.1",
    "react-stack-grid": "^0.7.1",
    "react-stonecutter": "^0.3.10",
    "react-table": "^7.0.0-rc.15",
    "react-web-tabs": "^1.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "webpack": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to use the material-ui latest version

Comment: @JayParmar : it will be done by a command line upgrade command or individually I will be doing that for each package that I have used ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you see the log, for old packages, it gives a Warning and not an Error. The error is actually this line: `npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...on" : "10.16.3"`

`npm ERR!}'`

Since you have not included the entire log, with this, I can guess it is possibly an ambiguity issue due to references not properly resolved!

Open command prompt/powershell/terminal, etc. with admin privilege. Do as below: -

- `sudo npm cache clean --force`
- `sudo npm cache verify`
- Delete the `package-lock.json` file located in `C:\Users\<your_username>`

Try installing your project dependencies now from your project folder with `npm i`.

Note: - If this doesn't work, follow the same process as above (again) and uninstall the `npm` and `node` and reinstall it. It should work then!

Comment: Yes indeed, npm:WARN gone after cache cleaning.

Answer (score -2):

Try upgrading to `@material-ui/core`.

`material-ui` package is deprecated.

Comment: so shall I simply remove "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5", from my package.json and again do - "npm install @material-ui/core" from cmd ?