# npm copyfiles not working, giving ELIFECYCLE error

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I have installed copyfiles using: npm install -g copyfiles@2.0.0
I have also added the scripts in the package.json file.
Here is the package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch-shell",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch-scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
    "watch-shell": "parallelshell \"npm run watch-scss\" \"npm run lite\"",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "copyfonts": "copyfiles -f \"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*\" \"dist/fonts\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "less": "^3.11.3",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "onchange": "^3.3.0",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

Here is the terminal output I am getting:

```
$ npm run copyfonts

> confusion@1.0.0 copyfonts C:\Users\verma\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> copyfiles -f "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*" "dist/fonts"

'copyfiles' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 copyfonts: `copyfiles -f "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*" "dist/fonts"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 copyfonts script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\verma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-06T19_20_40_248Z-debug.log
```

And the debug file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'copyfonts'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'precopyfonts', 'copyfonts', 'postcopyfonts' ]
5 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~precopyfonts: confusion@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~copyfonts: confusion@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~copyfonts: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~copyfonts: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\verma\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\verma\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\verma\bin;C:\Users\verma\Downloads\results\poppler-0.68.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\verma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin;C:\Users\verma\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~copyfonts: CWD: C:\Users\verma\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
10 silly lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~copyfonts: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'copyfiles -f "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*" "dist/fonts"'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~copyfonts: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~copyfonts: Failed to exec copyfonts script
13 verbose stack Error: confusion@1.0.0 copyfonts: `copyfiles -f "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*" "dist/fonts"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid confusion@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\verma\Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "copyfonts"
18 verbose node v12.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error confusion@1.0.0 copyfonts: `copyfiles -f "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*" "dist/fonts"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 copyfonts script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried clearing the cache using: npm cache clean --force. But it's still giving me the same error as before.

Comment: Though you have mentioned that the package is installed globally, can you please check the command just by running `copyfiles --version` in the command prompt/bash/terminal, etc and let me know?

Comment: It shows: command not found.

Comment: It clearly means the `copyfiles` package is not installed properly. Try reinstalling it! If it still doesn't work or throws some error, try considering this answer by me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754354/npm-install-giving-error-after-so-many-warn/62760196#62760196

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem, but I tried with this npm install --save-dev copyfiles

Comment: I have had this problem, the solution is to use the command prompt as administrator. ie go find Command Prompt on your PC, then select Run as Administrator. Then run the command and you should find it all works as expected.