# verbose stack Error: functions@ start: `npm run shell`

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I've been trying to solve this problem for days,

Could one of you help me? Please do so.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~prestart: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~start: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/wuskamsmac/Desktop/challenge-amazon/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~start: CWD: /Users/wuskamsmac/Desktop/challenge-amazon
10 silly lifecycle functions@~start: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run shell' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ start: `npm run shell`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd /Users/wuskamsmac/Desktop/challenge-amazon
16 verbose Darwin 20.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.18.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error functions@ start: `npm run shell`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the functions@ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: There are several web posts suggesting this is either a bad node module or a VM with insufficient RAM.  https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8254

Comment: Not fully sure, but please check the accepted answer in the below link and try following the mentioned steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754354/npm-install-giving-error-after-so-many-warn/62760196#62760196

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me last time I had npm script already running in another terminal.